# How to send a csv file using Flask-Mail

Tags: python, csv, flask, flask-mail

I have a Flask app created and the code below is part of a view.

```
msg = Message("[STATSUMM] DATA REQUESTED", sender="mateobonnett@gmail.com",recipients=[form.email.data])

msg.attach('app/Covid/Files/Covid_19_2020-03-31.csv', 'application/octet-stream')

mail.send(msg)
```

It performs well when sending the email with no attachment. However, when attaching the csv file I get this error

```
TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not NoneType
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is it proper filepath? Confirm it first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several problem with the code snippet above:

1. You're not supposed to read the file directly on msg.attach
2. According [RFC7111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7111) mime type for csv file should be
   text/csv

```
with app.open_resource("app/Covid/Files/Covid_19_2020-03-31.csv") as fp:
    msg.attach("Covid_19_2020-03-31.csv", "text/csv", fp.read())
```

for more details about [Flask-Mail API](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/#api)